# How can I get the email address of a user who has just registered?

Tags: 8

I need to add a hash key to users on register, generated from their email address and the current time, I added the field 'field_subscription_key' to user's fields and I hooked into

> custom_newsletter_mail_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category)

in module's .module file, I have no idea how can I get the email address and time the user was created from these above parameters.

Also, I don't know how to get the user entity, so I would insert the hash key.

Comment: Those arguments are *not* what Drupal 8 receives on hook_user_insert(). Either you are not actually using Drupal 8 or you are using wrong examples/documentation

Comment: I got this hook from the drupal 8 api docs at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7.x

Comment: Make sure you read pages fully - you're using Drupal 8 but you're copying code from documentation that's clearly for Drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs on the core entities are really good. [Here are the docs on the User class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/class/User/8.4.x).

You should be able to get the email with:

```
$email = $account->getEmail();
```

And the created time with:

```
$created = $account->getCreatedTime();
```

Comment: I got both the email and created time using your syntax, i got the hash key from them, then i used $account->set('field_subscription_key',$key); $account->save(); to save the subscription key but for some reason this is not working, the main problem is i cannot find a way to print the values and debug from this hook.